# PySpark: Permission denied although permission is given

Tags: python, apache-spark, permissions, pyspark

I'm new to PySpark. I want to rewrite an existing Python program and use Spark. It already worked with SparkR, so I'm pretty sure that Python and Spark are installed correctly.

When I run a simple program in PySpark, everything seems alright. Here is a short example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, TimestampType, DoubleType, StringType

def lineToRow(line):
    (year, month, day, symbol, volume, price) = line.split("\t")
    # Python 2.x compatible timestamp generation
    dt = datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    return (dt, symbol, float(price))

def loadObservations(sparkContext, sqlContext, path):
    textFile = sparkContext.textFile(path)
    rowRdd = textFile.map(lineToRow)
    schema = StructType([
        StructField('timestamp', TimestampType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('price', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('group', StringType(), nullable=True),
    ])
    return sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, schema);

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Test")
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    file = '../01-Daten/test.csv'

    obs = loadObservations(sc, sqlContext, file)
    print(obs)
```

The output is:

```
DataFrame[timestamp: timestamp, price: double, group: string]
```

With data "test.csv":

```
Time,Price,Group
2017-12-01 0:00:00,20.17,Group1
2017-12-01 1:00:00,17.41,Group1
2017-12-01 2:00:00,16.08,Group2
2017-12-01 3:00:00,17.48,Group1
2017-12-01 4:00:00,20.48,Group2
2017-12-01 5:00:00,21.95,Group2
2017-12-01 6:00:00,24.59,Group2
2017-12-01 7:00:00,38.9,Group1
2017-12-01 8:00:00,46.94,Group2
2017-12-01 9:00:00,44.91,Group2
2017-12-01 10:00:00,43.29,Group1
2017-12-01 11:00:00,45.88,Group2
2017-12-01 12:00:00,42.5,Group2
2017-12-01 13:00:00,44.93,Group1
2017-12-01 14:00:00,45.6,Group2
2017-12-01 15:00:00,45.52,Group2
2017-12-01 16:00:00,48.4,Group1
2017-12-01 17:00:00,58.55,Group2
2017-12-01 18:00:00,46.99,Group2
2017-12-01 19:00:00,38.91,Group1
2017-12-01 20:00:00,36.03,Group1
2017-12-01 21:00:00,31.93,Group2
2017-12-01 22:00:00,31.01,Group2
2017-12-01 23:00:00,27.52,Group1
```

As soon as I want to see the first element in "obs" (I change the print to "print(obs.first())") I get an IOException, error: 13:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/cornelia/Dokumente/Arbeit/Programme/180124-ZR-Spark/02-Code/ZR-Analyse-Spark.py", line 57, in <module>
    print(obs.first())

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 982, in first
    return self.head()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 970, in head
    rs = self.head(1)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 972, in head
    return self.take(n)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 476, in take
    return self.limit(num).collect()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 438, in collect
    port = self._jdf.collectToPython()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o324.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/python3.6": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
29 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply$mcI$sp(Dataset.scala:2808)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2805)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2805)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2828)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:2805)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/python3.6": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
29 more
```

The required folder ("/usr/lib/python3.6") and all subfolders have all permissions: [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0gS5.png)

I tried many things and made a lot of Google searches. Any idea how to fix this? I am running python 3.6 on Ubuntu 17.10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently you're running spark from the folder where spark doesn't have permissions to write metadata(derby file). Try to create a new folder, grant read/write permissions and execute script from there

Comment: where should this folder be? Can you specify a little bit?

Comment: you can make it wherever you like. Just grant proper permissions. For example I have `/apps`, where I keep all the scripts and have permissions to write. You can just `cd /tmp` and execute your program from here to see if it works: `spark-submit --master local /path/to/your/script.py`

Comment: I executed the program from ``/tmp`` but I get the same exception.

Comment: You start spark from which user?

Comment: I hope, I got it right: I start Spark in my script. I execute it wih my user. When I execute it as ``sudo`` I get following: ``Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/', '/usr/local/bin']
/usr/local/bin/spark-submit: line 27: /bin/spark-class: file or directory not found``

Comment: Normally I start my programs within spyder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was referencing to the wrong path (`/usr/lib/python3.6`). I need to reference to `usr/bin/python`. Then everything works.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Giving Zeppelin another anaconda installation was one similar problem I faced. Turning back to /usr/bin/python2.7 cleared the exception.